# Convert language abbreviation to full name, e.g. en to English?

Tags: c#, globalization, cultureinfo

quick question, what's the best way to convert language a abbreviation to full name?
e.g. en to English?
Note, it's not en-US, it's just en, fr, de

C# please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure you can get it from just en... You can do this though if you know the rest of the abbrevation:

```
System.Globalization.RegionInfo info = new System.Globalization.RegionInfo("en-GB");
string countryName = info.EnglishName;
```

**Edit: Actually, you can do it:**

```
CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo("en");
string englishName = info.EnglishName;
```

Comment: Why didn't you just use CultureInfo the same way you used RegionInfo (see my answer)? Your version is overcomplicated.

Comment: Very true, changed it and +1ed you.

Answer (score 4):

```
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo x = new CultureInfo("en");
        string name = x.EnglishName;
```